# How to add update command for ImageButton in GridView ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, imagebutton

I am kinda lost.

I have a GridView with ItemTemplate.  I am trying to approve and reject booking using ImageButton but I do not know where and how to put the sql command to update booking status.

I need hints to continue my coding.

Here is my ItemTemplate for Accept and Reject imagebutton:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="acceptBooking"
         ImageUrl="~/images/accept.png"
  OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this booking?')) return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>                                  
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="rejectBooking"
         ImageUrl="~/images/reject.png"
  OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reject this booking?')) return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>                                  
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My SQLdatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [bookingScheduleID], [eventTitle], [week1], [week2], [week3], [week4], [week5], [week6], [week7], [week8], [exhibitorname], [boothAlias], [category], [status], [dateBook],[custNo] FROM [bookingschedule]" 
          >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I wish to update field [status] from table [bookingschedule]

My interface:
[image]

Comment: That is asp.net, not asp-classic

Comment: maybe the clientclick will call a js func that will call in case of true the sqlupdate cuz if ull put there a server onclick it will click'em both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any server-side code to handle the OnClientClick event? If so you just have to do your SQL logic in it while taking the result of the confirmation you asked. Otherwise make a js script to handle the SQL logic... I just hope that you have access to some kind of ID of [bookingschedule] if you want to update one.

Anyway, to your Where to put the code : in the hanldling of OnClientClick event. How is more to you to decide. You can use library `SqlClient` in `System.Data` library. Or use LINQ technology or even an Hibernate. All depend on you. Some research on the internet and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Hi, can further guide me how to do server-side code?
I just try use Update Command at client side for Accept button, it successfully update [status] to 1, but problem come when I want add update command for Reject button, only one UpdateCommand can be declare to update the row. I am lost

Comment: Sorry for duplicated post, this link show the coding for client side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835821/update-gridview-with-image-button
I do not have client side code