# Update Gridview with Image Button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, imagebutton

I have 2 image buttons, Accept and Reject. 
Accept button will update [status] to 1
Reject button will update [status] to 2

I had successfully use UpdateCommand to update Accept button

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bookingschedule] SET status='1'WHERE [bookingScheduleID] = @bookingScheduleID"
```

But, I do not know how to set update command for Reject button since I can declared UpdateCommand once only.

```
UpdateCommand2="UPDATE [bookingschedule] SET status='2'WHERE [bookingScheduleID] = @bookingScheduleID" (incorrect)
```

What should I do to make Reject button function? Where should i put this 2nd update command line:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bookingschedule] SET status='2'WHERE [bookingScheduleID] = @bookingScheduleID"
```

I do all this coding at client side:

**Accept Button:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action Approve">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="UpdateCommand"
  CommandName="update" ImageUrl="~/images/accept.png"
  OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this booking?')) return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Reject Button:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action Reject">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="UpdateCommand" CommandName="update" OnClick="reject"
  ImageUrl="~/images/reject.png"
  OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reject this booking?')) return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**SQL datasource:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [bookingScheduleID], [eventTitle], [week1], [week2], [week3], [week4], [week5], [week6], [week7], [week8], [exhibitorname], [boothAlias], [category], [status], [dateBook],[custNo] FROM [booking_all]" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bookingschedule] SET status='1'WHERE [bookingScheduleID] = @bookingScheduleID"
            >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="bookingScheduleID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a control to dynamically store/pass the status based on the button clicked

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bookingschedule] SET status=@Status WHERE [bookingScheduleID] = @bookingScheduleID"
```

then add

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="Status" ControlID="StatusSelectionControl" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
```

the propertyName should be relative to the control used - am assuming TextBox, but you can also use hidden field